# Differentiating complex series term by term

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Given the complex series $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{(z+n)(z-n)}$, under what conditions is $f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z}{(z+n)(z-n)} \right)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $z$ that is not an integer, your series is terms that are $\sim 1/n^2$, thus the series is absolutely convergent. The derivative is the series of the derivatives of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

The function has poles at $\pm n$, which are isolated (do not have accumulation points).
So f(z) is [meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) and thus differentiable.